# In ES6, how the methods of a JavaScript object are handled when they are created using a constructor

Tags: javascript-objects

Please see the below code

```
class Person{
   constructor(){
       this.name = 'John';
    }

   displayName(){
   console.log(this.name);
   }
}

let john = new Person();

console.log(john.displayName());
console.log(john.__proto__.displayName()); //It doesn't print the name
console.log(john);
```

I understand(from the above example) the methods in ES6 are placed as members in constructor's prototype(i.e. Person). i.e. : Person.prototype.displayName() which is assigned to john.**proto**.displayName()

My question here is, I am able to print name to the console by typing console.log(john.displayName()) but not by using console.log(john.**proto**.displayName()).

Also I am able to print the method definition by typing console.log(john.**proto**.displayName) but I am unable to call it.(using **proto**).

Comment: Have you tried finding a read on the subject?

Answer (score 0):

When accessing `john.__proto__.displayName` you essentially calling it "statically" which means the constructor is not ran, and any properties assign to "this" on it, are not there so `this.name` at that point is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

When you are accessing `john.displayName()`, you are accessing `name` property which have value 'John'. This is because the **constructor function** of the `Person` have run for it and the property `name` was assigned value 'John'.

But when you are running `john.__proto__.displayName()`, you are accessing the property of **prototype** of `john` object, ie. `Person`. Here the constructor function is not run. Therefore the value of `name` property is undefined.